# Find an upper bound for the integral using the estimation lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Gamma_r$ be the semi-circle centered at the origin from $z=r$ to $z=-r$ through the upper half of the complex plane.

I want to find an upper bound for $$\left \lvert \int_{\Gamma_r} \frac{1}{z^2+2z+2} \, dz\right \rvert$$

I know that in order to do this I can use the Estimation Lemma. In doing this I know that I need to find a lower bound for $|z^2+2z+2|$. I'm told that one such bound is $\frac{1}{2}r^2$. Why is this?

Comment: Depends on $r$ (and is wrong for some values of $r$). Are we assuming $r$ is large?

Comment: @DanielFischer My apologies, yes we're assuming $r$ is large.

Comment: $\lvert (z+1)^2+1\rvert \geqslant \lvert z+1\rvert^2 - 1 \geqslant (\lvert z\rvert - 1)^2 - 1 = \lvert z\rvert^2 - 2\lvert z\rvert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why is it then clear that this is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{2} r^2$?

Comment: It's not clear (of course not, it's only true for large enough $r = \lvert z\rvert$), but it's easy to find out when $r^2 - 2r \geqslant \frac{1}{2}r^2$.